# No node found for selector // Puppeteer Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Im trying to build a simple program that checks my college portal and notifies me when the portal changes.

I used Chrome's inspect feature to copy the selector but still error occurs.

I used the selector that pops on when I put my mouse on top of the source code and the error still occurs.

The only solution I found was to actually right click the button I want to find the selector for, then click inspect and then go back to the console and look up the selector.

How can I solve this problem?

```
await page.waitFor(10000);
await page.click('a#SLO_SS_STDNTCEN_SLO_SS_APP_STATUS.PSHYPERLINK');

await page.waitForSelector('a#SLO_SS_STDNTCEN_SLO_SS_APP_STATUS.PSHYPERLINK');
await page.click('a#SLO_SS_STDNTCEN_SLO_SS_APP_STATUS.PSHYPERLINK');
```

I expected for the computer to click on the selector I chose- which is correct without a doubt- but an error occurs: No node found for selector

Comment: It is worth to provide a small but complete script with the actual URL so that everybody can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Im working on a college portal so I doubt anyone can reproduce the issue- only people who have an account for the specific college I am looking for can access the page and go to the console to check on selectors